# Подскажите как изменить цвет строки в ListFragment

Tags: android, sqlite, cursoradaper

Здравствуйте. Пишу приложение для работы, которое представляет из себя список точек с возможностью сортировать по дням недели ,и по " мои не мои".. 
Переопределил метод SimpleCursorAdapter для изменения цвета строк. Но хотелось бы сделать это изменение в зависимости от параметра Мой или нет ,а не от чётности позиции.. Параметр "мой" хранится в SQLite в виде "1" в столбике "isMy". никак не могу сообразить как получить это значение в адаптере..

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter  {


public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        if (position % 2 == 0){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(238, 233, 233));
    }
    else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо работать не с `getView ()`, а с `bindBiew ()` и `newView ()` они имеют в аргументах `Cursor`, откуда и можно извлечь значение вашего поля.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getCursor().getInt(getCursor().getColumnIndex("isMy")) == 1){
    //столбец isMy = 1
} else {
   //столбец isMy = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы! В bindView

`if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ismy")).equals("1")){
}else{
}`

и всё отлично работает. Только в else условие должно быть обязательно,а то будут косяки))